# Sorting in gridview C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to sort the records on different parameters like *mobile no.* ,*registration date* , etc

My form looks like[image]

After entering the *mobile no.* when I click on search I get the following result :

[image]

Now I want to sort the records w.r.t registration date.

Here is my code for sorting the record:

```
private void SearchDate()
    {
        DataTable rt = GetRecords();
        DataView rd = new DataView(rt);
        string SearchRegdate = null;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtdate.Text))
        {
              SearchRegdate = string.Format("{0} '%{1}%'", gvUser.SortExpression, txtdate.Text);

        }
           rd.RowFilter = "registration_date like " + SearchRegdate;
           gvUser.DataSource = rd;
           gvUser.PageSize = 30;
           gvUser.DataBind();
    }
```

Here I am getting the error "Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.DateTime and System.String. "

Any solutions ??

Comment: What is the data type of `registration_date`? also do you need to `sort` or `filter` records?

Comment: data type is datetime and yes i want to filter the records . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your date to a string before using the like:

```
dt.Select("Convert(column1,System.String) like '2013'")
```

or  rd.RowFilter = "Convert(column1,System.String) like " + SearchRegdate;

You can check the full syntax here: [syntax reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Comment: thanks mate !

rd.RowFilter = "Convert(column1,System.String) like " + SearchRegdate;

this works fine . . .

Answer (score 0):

First of all I thinkg the syntax is wrong. What would come out of your statment is something like:

```
registration_date like <user sort expression> '%...%'
```

There may not be anything between the `like` and the filter expression `%...%`.

Also, the column `registration_date` is a `DateTime` - you can not compare it to a `string` using `like` - and this is what the error is saying. You could add a hidden computed column that contains the date as string and sort on that.

Comment: yes i converted the column to string and now it is working as expected. . . thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb386977.aspx) instead of RowFilter:

Simple example with DateTime:

Initialization:

```
var table = new DataTable("Dates");
var dateColumn = new DataColumn("Date", typeof (DateTime));
table.Columns.Add(dateColumn);

table.BeginLoadData();
table.LoadDataRow(new object[] {new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)}, true);
table.LoadDataRow(new object[] {new DateTime(2000, 1, 2)}, true);
table.LoadDataRow(new object[] {new DateTime(2001, 1, 1)}, true);
table.LoadDataRow(new object[] {new DateTime(2002, 1, 1)}, true);
table.EndLoadData();
```

The query with searched date text:

```
var someDateText = "2000";

var dataView = (from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                let dateTime = row.Field<DateTime>(0)
                where dateTime.ToString().Contains(someDateText)
                orderby dateTime
                select row).AsDataView();
```

After that you can also use RowFilter of created dataView to perform other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Linq`:

```
var rows = (from r in rt.AsEnumerable()
           where SqlFunctions
             .StringConvert(r.Field<DateTime>("registration_date")).Contains("1")
           select r).ToList();
```

Or if you want a datatable

```
DataTable dt = (aboveQuery).CopyToDataTable();
```